# .net ignite distributed cache on the same machine as the .net runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, ignite

I used ignite in a java project before, but was never exposed to the infrastructure/architecture setup...

Now I am have a .net project where I see a perfect need for a distributed in memory cache and I am turning to apacheignite-net. 
The .net project is a set of backend services (wcf & amqp). these services can scale horizontally: I can add additional servers with these services for higher throughput.

But I am needs advice/pointers on ignite deployment/infrastructure along with .net: 
 - I can't add additional/dedicated servers for caching: so I am thinking about having both my .net services and apacheignite-net on the same box.
 - the objects that I would need to cache (right now seeking them from DB with every request) are not that large but I do not need all of them cached: so a combination of read-through / eviction policy ?

My questions is: is it a normal/safe thing to have both the JVM for ignite and these .net services on the same box. I read trough the performance tips, but still seek input from the wiser/experienced. I can always add more memory to these servers but not much cores: these .net services do not consume all provided cpu, they are backed by an RDBMS, and I can ask for a bit more ram if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to embed an Ignite node into each service instance and create a `REPLICATED` cache to cache the data (you can configure read/write-through [1] and evictions [2] if needed). With such deployment each service instance will have all the cached data locally, so reads will be very fast.

To start an embedded node simply call `Ignition.Start()` with the proper configuration on start. Here is a small example: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/getting-started-1#first-ignite-data-grid-application

[1] https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/persistent-store

[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/evictions